# Will a key in sql still stay a key in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, key, concatenation

Let's say I have a mysql table called FISH with fields A, B and C.

I run `SELECT * FROM FISH`. This gets me a view with all fields. So, if A was a key in the original table, is it also a key in the view? Meaning, if I have a table FISH2, and I ran

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM FISH) D, (SELECT * FROM FISH2) E WHERE D.A = E.A
```

Will the relevant fields still be keys?

Now, let's take this 1 step further. If I run

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(A,B) AS DUCK, C FROM FISH) D, (SELECT CONCAT(A,B) AS DUCK2, C FROM FISH2) E WHERE D.DUCK = E.DUCK2
```

If A and B were keys in the original tables, will their concatenation also be a key?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is a key in `fish`, any projection on fish only, will produce a resultset where A is still unique.

A join between table fish and any table with 1:1 relation (such as fish_type) will produce a result set where A is unique.

A join with another table that has 1:M or M:M relation from fish (such as fish_beits) will NOT produce a result where A is unique, unless you provide a filter predicate on the "other" side (such as `bait='Dynamite'`).

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM FISH) D, (SELECT * FROM FISH2) E WHERE D.A = E.A
```

...is logically equivalent to the following statement, and most databases (including MySQL) will perform the transformatiion:

```
select *
  from fish
  join fish2 on(fish.a = fish2.a)
```

Whether A is still unique in the resultset depends on the key of `fish2` and their relation (see above).

Concatenation does not preserve uniqueness. Consider the following case:

```
concat("10", "10") => "1010"
concat("101", "0") => "1010"
```

Therefore, your final query...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT CONCAT(A,B) AS DUCK, C FROM FISH) D
      ,(SELECT CONCAT(A,B) AS DUCK2, C FROM FISH2) E 
 WHERE D.DUCK = E.DUCK2
```

...won't (necessarily) produce the same result as

```
select * 
  from fish 
  join fish2 on(
       fish.a = fish2.a
   and fish.b = fish2.b
  )
```

I wrote *necessarily* because the collisions depend on the actual values. I hunted down a bug about some time ago where the root cause was exactly this. The code had worked for several years before the bug manifested itself.

Comment: as for the concatenation - perhaps my question was wrong. I am not looking for uniqueness, I'm looking for fast queries, such that come when an index is used (and not specifically key). So, after the concatenation, will the index properties still exist?

Comment: no, the index will not be used. If you create an index on (a,b) and use the form I used in my last example the index will be used in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If by "key" you mean "unique", yes, tuples of a cartesian product over unique values will be unique.
(One can prove it via by reductio ad absurdum.)

Comment: by key I mean that it would still take a very short time to run queries.. the unique part I understand :)

Comment: Note though that string concatenation does not preserve this property: consider  (A, AF, AFO, AFOO) in set 1 and (FOOL, OOL, OL, L) in set 2.  The concat of their cartesian product will have several AFOOL.

Answer (score 0):

For step 1, think of a view as a subquery containing everything in the `AS` clause when `CREATE VIEW` was executed.

For example, if view `v` is created as `SELECT a, b, c FROM t`, then when you execute...

```
SELECT * FROM v WHERE a = some_value
```

...it's conceptually treated as...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a, b, c FROM t) WHERE a = some_value
```

Any database with a decent optimizer will notice that column `a` is passed straight into the results and that that it can take advantage of the indexing in `t` (if there is any) by moving it into the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE a = some_value)
```

This all happens behind the scenes and is not an optimization you need to do yourself.  Obviously, it can't do that for every condition in the `WHERE` clause, but understanding where you can is part of the art of writing a good optimizer.

For step 2, the concatenated keys will be part of intermediate results, and whether or not the database decides they need indexing is an implementation detail.  Also note fche's comment about duplication.

If your database has a query plan explainer, running it and learning to interpret the results will give you a lot of insight about what makes your queries run fast and what slows them down.